# Getting error in puppet node_gce

Tags: puppet, puppet-enterprise

I am getting the following error while running the `puppet help node_gce` command:

```
[root@puppetmaster ~]# puppet help node_gce
Faraday: you may want to install system_timer for reliable timeouts
Error: Could not autoload puppet/face/node_gce/add_metadata: "--user=": already defined in puppet
Error: Could not load help for the face node_gce.
Please check the error logs for more information.

Detail: "Could not autoload puppet/face/node_gce/add_metadata: "--user=": already defined in puppet"

Error: Try 'puppet help help help' for usage
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Some more detail around what are you trying to do on which machine might be helpful